# The description for the "merge tags" has not been updated

Tags: support, status-completed, moderator-tools, tag-merge-utility

The description given for the "merge tags" page has not been updated; the label of the text fields has been changed, but the description still references the old labels.

[image: screenshot #1]

[image: screenshot #1]

The screenshots are for http://drupal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description for the "Merge tags" page has been updated.

[image: screenshot]